# Why do my SWR calculations result in negative values?

Tags: impedance-matching

I am doing some calculations with matching networks.

[image: simple matching circuit]

$$L=3.7499999999999997e-06H$$

$$C=5e-11F$$

$$f=7 Mhz$$

$$Z_1=50+0j\Omega$$

I computed the resulting impedance as:

$$Z_x = {Z_1}-{Z_L} = Z_1-{(0+2\pi f Lj)}$$
$$Z_2 = {1\over({1 \over Z_x}-{1 \over {Z_c}})} = {1\over({1 \over Z_x}-{-1 \over {2\pi f C}})}$$

$$Z_2=(41.06137715620962+21.594461171245698j)\Omega$$

I want to know what the SWR would be if I connect a mismatched load at Z2.

$$Zload=123.3-234.6j\Omega$$

$$\Gamma = {{Z_{load}-Z_2} \over {Z_{load}+Z_2}}$$
$$swr = {{1+|\Gamma|} \over {1-|\Gamma|}}$$

$$\Gamma = (0.9406193459943022-0.3397229416732794j)$$
$$swr=-22673.732362594943$$

The SWR is negative, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio) says:

> Since the magnitude of Γ always falls in the range [0,1], the SWR is always greater than or equal to unity

I expected the SWR to be bad, but not negative. Where are my calculations incorrect? What is the meaning of negative SWR?

Observe the following calculations:

Comment: Please show formulaically the SWR calculation you are making and list the values for load, inductor and capacitor then, just to ensure there is no ambiguity, show the circuit you are ambiguously describing with words.

Answer (score 1):

Your reflection coefficient is actually amplification.  Dropping off the j from the impedance of the capacitor changes it to a negative resistor, which amplifies. Fix and recalculate.

I must admit that the whole calculation looks undecipherable mess and I cannot guarantee inserting j is the only needed fix. I do not claim that you cannot understand the calculation idea, it's only me.

Comment: How would you calculate the equivalent impedance? How would you arrive at Z2?

Comment: Cannot do it. I do not have a slightest idea where's the mismatched load (123.3−234.6j)Ω and where's the signal source that sees the reflection coefficient you want to calculate and present as VSWR. They should be drawn to the diagram. I simply cannot be sure what in the hell is the symbol Z1? It occurs in formulas and on an arrow. The same for Z2. Then there's Zx which doesnt exist elsewhere than in the cryptic formulas. Before you wake up the moderator to get me fired remember, that I do NOT claim you don't know what you do.

Comment: @Maximilian (continued) but there's another  answer which wipes your formulas and the hidden logic behind them directly to the scrapheap, guesses what you might want and shows the old school straightforward calculation to get it. The answer is well written. I'm not allowed to comment nor upvote it due my low status.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand your logic without spending an hour back calculating what you're trying to do. A matching network is normally used to match a coax cable to a load (e.g., an antenna) that may have a wonky impedance. Thus, lets take a fresh look at the problem and see if this jibes with what you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcXNWD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$  Z_o = 50 \$  which is the feed line impedance.
\$ s = j \omega = j\ 2\pi f \$
\$ f = 7 \; MHz  \$
\$ L = 3.75 \ \mu H  \$
\$ C = 50 \ pF  \$
\$ Z = 123.3 - j234.6 \$

\$ Z_{in} = {sL+{1 \over {sC+{1 \over Z}}}} = {{s^2LCZ + sL + Z}\over {sCZ+1}} = 51.992 + j0.876 \$

\$ \Gamma = {{Z_{in}-Z_o} \over {Z_{in}+Z_o}} = 0.020+j8.416 \times 10^{-3}  \$

\$ VSWR = {{1+|\Gamma|} \over {1-|\Gamma|}} = 1.044  \$

Thus, a pretty good match.